# ADFS as proxy to some IDP

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, exchange-server, saml, adfs

As far as I know, Exchange does support WS-Federation, but it does not support SAML. At the same time I have IDP that does support SAML, but does not support WS-Federation.

Is it possible to configure ADFS as proxy? For example: Exchange OWA/ECP -> redirect to ADFS using WS-Fed -> and ADFS speaks to IDP using SAML -> user is getting transparently authenticated using IDP?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   AFAIK, if you are configuring Exchange on premises mail server, then you must have AD in your environment, thus, when Exchange OWA/ECP forwards requests to ADFS, those will be purely using WS-Fed protocol or internal Kerberos authentication protocol. So, if you want to forward credentials from the ADFS to the third-party SaaS platform, then a relying party trust must be formed with that IdP to which SAML token are supported.

•   Thus, you should create a SAML 2.0 provider supporting RPT with the IdP platform (3rd party) in ADFS for SAML supported authentication. Though, you can’t authenticate claims with the 3rd party IdP by forwarding through ADFS but can send the claim tokens as authenticated attributes to the other IdP.

•   Therefore, what you are asking is not possible as Exchange ECP passing claims to ADFS in WS-Fed and then forwarding them to the IdP in SAML supported token as ADFS doesn’t support forwarding the identities to other IdP for authentication or transforming the credentials protocol from WS-Fed to SAML.

Please find the below link for more details: -

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/adfs-deep-dive-comparing-ws-fed-saml-and-oauth/ba-p/257584

For configuration of SAML 2.0 service provider in ADFS, please refer the link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/configure-saml2-settings